# Using Memory Mapped I/O to load a 2-digit integer in MIPS Assembly

Tags: mips

I am working with MIPS Assembly in the Mars simulator and I am attempting to set it up so that I can enter any 2-digit number (ex: 24) into the Keyboard and Display MMIO Simulator and then take it from MMIO addresses and put it into my registers for manipulation. This technique will use polling, which I understand to some degree.

I can load individual characters and place their ascii value into my registers using the following code (inside .text):

```
main:
    lui $t0, 0xFFFF   #$t0 = 0xFFFF0000

poll:                 # polling procedure
    lw $t1, 0($t0) 
    andi $t1, $t1, 0x0001
    beq $t1, $zero, poll 

    lw $a0, 4($t0)    # load word into register $a0
```

Is it possible in this case for MMIO to treat the input as an immediate and to take in two at once? If not, then are there any known workarounds to this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Is it possible in this case for MMIO to treat the input as an immediate and to take in two at once?"

Comment: No and no. The mars MMIO interface is quite simple--too simple to do what you'd like. The code you already have is optimal. On real H/W _some_ devices have a combined status/data register (e.g. status in upper 16 bits and data in lower 16 bits) but usually they're separate registers. Nice idea, but when writing a device driver, one has to write the driver to the limitations of the device. For mars MMIO, status is offset 0 and data is offset 4--no way to fetch both in a single instruction. What you're hoping for are offsets of 0,2 which could be fetched in a single inst